# Using T-SQL DATEADD and DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to understand the code that someone wrong to implement the following requirements in calculating a date:

The derived JE_ACCTNG_DT is set equal to the last day of the prior month of the current year when the feed is created and sent.
For example, if the current year is 2013, the JE_ACCTNG_DT will be the following based on the quarter the feed is sent:

- JE_ACCTNG_DT = 3/31/2013 for 1st quarter feed sent on 4/1/2013
- JE_ACCTNG_DT = 6/30/2013 for 2nd quarter feed sent on 7/1/2013
- JE_ACCTNG_DT = 9/30/2013 for the 3rd quarter feed sent on 10/1/2013
- JE_ACCTNG_DT = 12/31/2013 for the 4th quarter feed sent on 1/1/2014

I see that someone implemented the code like this and it seems to give the right answer for the examples given in the requirements, if the datetime result is converted to a date data type (the time portion is dropped)

```
DECLARE @FEED_DT datetime 

SET @FEED_DT = '4/1/2013'
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT),0))


SET @FEED_DT = '7/1/2013'
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT),0))
--2013-06-30 23:59:59.000

SET @FEED_DT = '10/1/2013'
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT),0))
--2013-09-30 23:59:59.000


SET @FEED_DT = '1/1/2014'
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT),0))
--2013-09-30 23:59:59.000
```

What is confusing me is that the DATEDIFF function accepts the following arguments: A datepart and two dates

DATEDIFF (datepart ,startdate ,enddate )

If you notice above, the code set the date part to "m" but passed zero for the 2nd parameter when a date is expected.

```
DECLARE @FEED_DT datetime = '4/1/2013'
DECLARE @DateAddResult as int 

SET @DateAddResult = DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT)
select @DateAddResult 
--1359
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, @DateAddResult,0))
--2013-03-31 23:59:59.000
```

What is the code really doing? I would've expected an error. Did it coerce the 0 value to a date?

I'm thinking that what the requirements should really be is to calculate the last day of the previous quarter. This is how I would do it.

```
SELECT dateadd(day, -1, DATEADD(quarter,DATEDIFF(quarter,'1900/01/01', GETDATE()), '1900/01/01')) as FirstDayOfQuarter
```

Comment: Also please stop using lazy shorthand like mm and m. If you mean month, type `MONTH`.

Comment: Agreed about m and mm. You're two comments combined gave me my answer. thank you.

Comment: Also a couple of other things: change the `0` to `'19000101'` so that it isn't ambiguous and confusing. And stop using this silly "subtract a second" trick. It's dangerous. If you're going to be performing a lot of date range queries, please read [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) in full.

Comment: I agree. I dislike this code for all the reasons stated. Including that it has no comments. If someone summarizes this info, I'll mark the answer. I would do it but I don't want to steal you ideas. I think the real requirements are to find the last day of the previous quarter for a specified date. If this were provided in the answer, that would be a great bonus.

Comment: Stop thinking about the last day of the quarter. Think about the first day of the next quarter, which is always much easier to calculate, and all data types will work correctly with >= start of this quarter and < start of next quarter.

Comment: PS it's perfectly fine to self-answer.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using SQL Server 2008 based on the tag, but just in case you have access to 2012 check out the new EOMonth function.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/09/20/sql-server-denali-date-and-time-functions-eomonth-a-quick-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

Given this:

`select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT),0)`)

Let's take it one piece at a time...

```
DATEDIFF(m,0,@FEED_DT)
```

...calculates the number of whole integer months that has alapsed from date value zero (which is evaluated as 1-1-1900) to the date value started in the datetime field @FEED_DT. Let's say that this value is @ElapsedMonthsSinceZero and replace this variable into the original nested function, giving:

select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, @ElapsedMonthsSinceZero,0))

Now let's evaluate this part:

```
DATEADD(mm, @ElapsedMonthsSinceZero,0)
```

This adds the same number of months to the Date "zero", i.e. 1-1-1900, which brings you to the first day of the month of the date @FEED_DT. Essentially, what we did so far was calculate the whole number of months that have elapsed from date 0, truncating off any day beyond day 1 into the month. This gives us @FirstDayOfFEED_DT. Replacing that into the function gives us...

```
select DATEADD(s,-1,@FirstDayOfFEED_DT)
```

Now that we have the first day of the month of the date @FEED_DT, subtracting 1 gives us the last day of the previous month.

I guess I was just thrown off by the discrepancy where a value of 0 was passed instead of a date.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you add some days in a new column and you hava a stored procedure of a parameter @date and you want to add current date to that parameter and get result in days.

```
 DateAdd(days,@date,Getdate())
```